# Chrome extension code update strategy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first google chrome extension. One of the things that concerns me is that I may need to perform regular updates since the extension is quite intricate.

**DETAILS**:
-The extension uses content scripts to manipulate the DOM. The content scripts manipulate the DOM by injecting web components.
- My extension relies on some external dependencies such as underscore, backbone and jQuery

In brief, I've heard about about the Web Store API but I am interesting in any thoughts about this topic.

How does one typically handle updates for external dependencies such as jQuery, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to include those external depencencies as part of your code and not link to the cdn or external repository. This is also explained in the official docs.
If for some reason you must update the library just publish a new version of the extension taking into account that it normally takes a day until chrome upgrades your users.
There are a few exceptions. For example google recommends that their google analytics library be linked and injected. Its slower and less efficient but some libraries ask you to do it.

Comment: Are the users notified about the update? Is it seamless?

Comment: The users are notified only if the extension needs new permissions (and extension is disabled until they reapprove). Its not 100% seamless. Extension can be updated while running which breaks a few things like messaging to the background page. You can also hook to an event that tells you the extension has an update so you decide to update then or later